# GeoServer WMS URL is taking much time to load

Tags: asp.net, geoserver, wms

We have two GeoServer URLs, on which one is taking much time, while other is loading the map quickly.

URL, which is taking more than 8 minutes to load,

```
https://geoserverhost:8443/geoserver/MapData/wms?VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=MapData:World English&STYLES=&SRS=EPSG:4326&BBOX=-7.19547556452724,-0.433061029346547,113.414400564691,36.8387409689189&WIDTH=1152&HEIGHT=356&FORMAT=image/png&BGCOLOR=0xADDAFE&EXCEPTIONS=application/vnd.ogc.se_blank
```

URL, which is working fine,

```
https://geoserverhost:8443/geoserver/MapData/wms?VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=MapData:World English&STYLES=&SRS=EPSG:4326&BBOX=-71.8405417474227,-24.717791059626,174.861477607797,51.5199857550079&WIDTH=1152&HEIGHT=356&FORMAT=image/png&BGCOLOR=0xADDAFE&EXCEPTIONS=application/vnd.ogc.se_blank
```

Only the difference is of coordinates (BBOX parameter).

I checked the same URL, with tiled=true and transparent=true, but still it is taking time.

After debugging, it seems, aspmap is not generating BBOX values accurately as per geoserver.

My questions:

1. In geoserver caching is enabled, but when we load tiles with aspmap, it is not caching. everytime, it is taking time to load tiles. How to enable caching, if we use asp map and integrate geoserver in that.
2. Why above mentioned URL is taking time to load tiles. Mentioned URLs are generated by aspmap code.

Code is as below,

```
private void AddWmsLayer(CGeoServerMapConfig objGeoServerMapConfig)
{
    string METHOD_NAME = "AddWmsLayer() ";
    LogMessage(string.Concat(className, METHOD_NAME, ISConstants.METHOD_ENTERED), MessageWriter.ISEnumLogLevel.DEBUG, loggerName);

    string transferprotocol = string.Empty;
    if (ConfigReader.EnableSecureTransferProtocol != null)
    {
        if (ConfigReader.EnableSecureTransferProtocol == SystemCommonConfiguration.SECURETRANSFERPROTOCOL_ENABLED)
        {
            transferprotocol = ISConstants.TRANSFER_PROTOCOL_HTTPS;
        }
        else
        {
            transferprotocol = ISConstants.TRANSFER_PROTOCOL_HTTP;
        }
    }

    string wmsUrl = transferprotocol + ISConstants.SEPARATER_COLON + ISConstants.FORWARD_SLASH + ISConstants.FORWARD_SLASH;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(objGeoServerMapConfig.HostName) &&
        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(objGeoServerMapConfig.Port) &&
        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(objGeoServerMapConfig.Workspace) &&
        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(objGeoServerMapConfig.WMSVersion) &&
        objGeoServerMapConfig.GeoServerLayers != null && objGeoServerMapConfig.GeoServerLayers.GeoServerLayer != null)
    {
        try
        {
            
            wmsUrl += objGeoServerMapConfig.HostName; //Geoserver HostName
            wmsUrl += ISConstants.SEPARATER_COLON;  // ISConstants.SEPARATER_COLON = :
            wmsUrl += objGeoServerMapConfig.Port;   // Geoserver Port
            wmsUrl += ISConstants.FORWARD_SLASH + ISConstants.CONST_GEOSERVER_URL_GEOSERVER +
                      ISConstants.FORWARD_SLASH;    //ISConstants.FORWARD_SLASH +  ISConstants.CONST_GEOSERVER_URL_GEOSERVER + ISConstants.FORWARD_SLASH = /geoserver/
            wmsUrl += objGeoServerMapConfig.Workspace; //Geoserver workspace Name
            wmsUrl += ISConstants.FORWARD_SLASH + ISConstants.CONST_GEOSERVER_URL_WMS +
                      ISConstants.WILD_CARD_QUESTION_MARK;  //ISConstants.FORWARD_SLASH + ISConstants.CONST_GEOSERVER_URL_WMS + ISConstants.WILD_CARD_QUESTION_MARK = /wms?

            WmsLayer wms = new WmsLayer(wmsUrl,
                new AspMap.Rectangle(-180, 90, 180, -90));
            
            LogMessage(string.Concat(className, METHOD_NAME, "WMS URL : " + wmsUrl), MessageWriter.ISEnumLogLevel.INFO, loggerName);
            wms.ImageFormat = (ImageFormat)objGeoServerMapConfig.ImageFormat;   // Image format = Image/png
            wms.Version = objGeoServerMapConfig.WMSVersion; // WMS = 1.1.1
            wms.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(objMapConfig.TileLayerConfig.BackColor);    // 0xADDAFE

            string[] arrGeoServerLayer = objGeoServerMapConfig.GeoServerLayers.GeoServerLayer;

            foreach (string geoServerLayer in arrGeoServerLayer)
            {
                string layerName = objGeoServerMapConfig.Workspace + ISConstants.SEPARATER_COLON +
                                   geoServerLayer;
                wms.AddLayer(layerName);    //Added layers
            }
            
            // add the WMS layer to the map
            AspMap.Layer wmsLayer = map.AddLayer(wms);
            
            // set the coordinate system of the map to the coordinate system of the MSRMAPS WMS layer
            map.CoordinateSystem = CoordSystem.WGS1984;
           
            // limit the full extent of the map to the extent of the WMS layer
            map.FullExtent = wmsLayer.Extent;
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            LogMessage(string.Concat(className, METHOD_NAME, " Exception : " + ex.ToString()), MessageWriter.ISEnumLogLevel.ERROR, loggerName);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        string strLogmessage = string.Concat(this.className, METHOD_NAME, "Geoserver Configured values are not valid. ");
        string strSensitiveLogmessage = string.Concat("IPAddress : ", objGeoServerMapConfig.HostName, ", Port : ", objGeoServerMapConfig.Port, ", Workspace : ", objGeoServerMapConfig.Workspace, ", WMS Version : ", objGeoServerMapConfig.WMSVersion, " or GeoServer layers is not valid in ASP map configuration in case of GeoServer.");
        LogMessage(strLogmessage, MessageWriter.ISEnumLogLevel.ERROR, loggerName, strSensitiveLogmessage);
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }
    LogMessage(string.Concat(className, METHOD_NAME, ISConstants.METHOD_EXITED), MessageWriter.ISEnumLogLevel.DEBUG, loggerName);
}
```

Zoomlevel information are as below,

```
<ZoomLevels>
        <ZoomLevel Name="0" Value="150000000" />
        <ZoomLevel Name="1" Value="90000000" />
        <ZoomLevel Name="2" Value="44000000" />
        <ZoomLevel Name="3" Value="18000000" />
        <ZoomLevel Name="4" Value="9000000" />
        <ZoomLevel Name="5" Value="4500000" />
        <ZoomLevel Name="6" Value="2000000" />
        <ZoomLevel Name="7" Value="1000000" />
        <ZoomLevel Name="8" Value="500000" />
        <ZoomLevel Name="9" Value="250000" />
        <ZoomLevel Name="10" Value="100000" />
        <ZoomLevel Name="11" Value="34000" />
        <ZoomLevel Name="12" Value="17000" />
        <ZoomLevel Name="13" Value="8400" />
        <ZoomLevel Name="14" Value="6000" />
        <ZoomLevel Name="15" Value="3400" />
        <ZoomLevel Name="16" Value="1800" />
      </ZoomLevels>
```

At the initial zoomlevels, it is taking much time. for zoomlevel 2 and 3, it is taking more than 5 mins.

- IDE: .NET 4.0 (64-bit)
- OS where code is running: Windows Server 2012 R2
- OS where geoserver is present: Windows Server 2022 Standard

I need a reason why URL is taking time to load for particular coordinates.

Edit : In geoserver, open street map data is there.

Comment: what does "BBOX is not generating accurately as per geoserver." mean? If you want the cache to be used then you need to request tiles from the WMTS end point not the WMS. You still don't say what your data is or where you are storing it so it is impossible to answer this question (as I said [before](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/467490/79))

Comment: @IanTurton I mean, aspmap is not generating BBOX values accurately as per geoserver.  And In geoserver, open street map data is there. and please update, if any info required and which information you required ?